# How to adjust position of scroll in the scrollpane

Tags: java, swing

I have created JTextpane and inserted components inside textpane (components like Jtextarea). (vertical scrollbar of )Jscrollpane of JTextpane is automatically set to bottom when I insert new components in that JTextpane. I want to  keep it to be set to  the top position. How can I do this

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a utility class I use.  It can be used to scroll to the top, bottom, left, right or horizonatal / vertical center of a `JScrollPane`.

```
public final class ScrollUtil {
    public static final int NONE = 0, TOP = 1, VCENTER = 2, BOTTOM = 4, LEFT = 8, HCENTER = 16, RIGHT = 32;
    private static final int OFFSET = 100; // Required for hack (see below).

    private ScrollUtil() {
    }

    /**
     * Scroll to specified location.  e.g. <tt>scroll(component, BOTTOM);</tt>.
     *
     * @param c JComponent to scroll.
     * @param part Location to scroll to.  Should be a bit-wise OR of one or moe of the values:
     * NONE, TOP, VCENTER, BOTTOM, LEFT, HCENTER, RIGHT.
     */
    public static void scroll(JComponent c, int part) {
        scroll(c, part & (LEFT|HCENTER|RIGHT), part & (TOP|VCENTER|BOTTOM));
    }

    /**
     * Scroll to specified location.  e.g. <tt>scroll(component, LEFT, BOTTOM);</tt>.
     *
     * @param c JComponent to scroll.
     * @param horizontal Horizontal location.  Should take the value: LEFT, HCENTER or RIGHT.
     * @param vertical Vertical location.  Should take the value: TOP, VCENTER or BOTTOM.
     */
    public static void scroll(JComponent c, int horizontal, int vertical) {
        Rectangle visible = c.getVisibleRect();
        Rectangle bounds = c.getBounds();

        switch (vertical) {
            case TOP:     visible.y = 0; break;
            case VCENTER: visible.y = (bounds.height - visible.height) / 2; break;
            case BOTTOM:  visible.y = bounds.height - visible.height + OFFSET; break;
        }

        switch (horizontal) {
            case LEFT:    visible.x = 0; break;
            case HCENTER: visible.x = (bounds.width - visible.width) / 2; break;
            case RIGHT:   visible.x = bounds.width - visible.width + OFFSET; break;
        }

        // When scrolling to bottom or right of viewport, add an OFFSET value.
        // This is because without this certain components (e.g. JTable) would
        // not scroll right to the bottom (presumably the bounds calculation
        // doesn't take the table header into account.  It doesn't matter if
        // OFFSET is a huge value (e.g. 10000) - the scrollRectToVisible method
        // still works correctly.

        c.scrollRectToVisible(visible);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I have found that the easiest way to do this is the following:

```
public void scroll(int vertical) {        
    switch (vertical) {
        case SwingConstants.TOP:
            getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
            break;
        case SwingConstants.CENTER:
            getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
            getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(getVerticalScrollBar().getValue() / 2);
            break;
        case SwingConstants.BOTTOM:  
            getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
            break;
    }
}
```

I placed this in an object which extended JScrollPane but you could also add the name of your JScrollPane before all the `getVertivalScrollBar()`.  There is two `setValue()`s for CENTER because `getMaximum()` returns the bottom of the `JScrollBar`, not the lowest value it goes to.  This also works for Horizontal Scrolling using `getHorizontalScrollBar()` in place of `getverticalScrollBar()`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to set the [`DefaultCaret`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultCaret.html) update policy to `NEVER_UPDATE`. See the article [*Text Area Scrolling*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) for other uses.

Answer (score 2):

This works too:

```
JTextArea. myTextArea;

// ...

myTextArea.select(0, 0);   // force the scroll value to the top
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation why your code solves the question, so the questioner can avoid similar issues maybe better adapt your suggestion to his code.

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods that you can use, depending on what is inside the scrollpane. See [the tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#api), the very last section.

Answer (score 0):

jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(1);

Answer (score -2):

ScrollPane's scroll value is always between ( 0.0 - 1 )
for example

0.0 = 0%
0.1 = 10%
0.2 = 20%
0.25 = 25%
.... so on

And you can adjust the scroll position using these values. For example, in JavaFX

```
// suppose this is the scrollpane
ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane();

// to scroll the scrollpane horizontally 10% from its current position
pane.setHvalue(pane.getHvalue() + 0.1);

// to scroll 100%
pane.setHvalue(1);

and so on...
```

apply logic as you need