# Java - Can't scroll down JTextArea if setEditable(false)

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JTextArea` which is not editable (`setEditable(false)`) inside a `JScrollPane` and I want it to automatically scroll so the last line is visible as text is added to the area (using `append()`).

I've already tried moving the caret, selecting all the text, and using DefaultCaret but I can not get it to scroll. Is there a way to accomplish this?

This is what I have tried:
https://gist.github.com/Greffin28/f38bb9c9ad8281de00e2

Comment: Hint: It's hard to debug words ;-)

Comment: How is this question unclear. It seems vary clear to me - `I want it to automatically scroll so the last line is visible as text is added to the area (using append()).`. The OP is simply asking to be pointed in the right direction. Is that not what a forum is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always enclose `JTextArea` in [JScrollPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) otherwise it will not work when no of rows are greater than the window height.

To set the scroll position read this post [How to adjust position of scroll in the scrollpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544758/how-to-adjust-position-of-scroll-in-the-scrollpane)

Sample code:

```
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setText("abc xyz \n\n\n\n\nabc xyz \n\n\n\n\nabc xyz \n\n\n\n\nabc xyz \n\n\n\n\nabc xyz \n\n\n\n\nabc xyz \n\n\n\n\nabc xyz \n\n\n\n\nabc xyz \n\n\n\n\nabc xyz \n\n\n\n\nabc xyz \n\n\n\n\nabc xyz \n\n\n\n\n");

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    // now add scrollPane  to your desired panel.
```

[image]

Comment: already add it to JScrollPanel forgot to tell.. let me edit that..

Comment: Its working for me. Should I share you code.

Comment: oh wait.. i meant automatically sorry :( my english are pretty bad

Comment: Try `chatScroll.getVerticalScrollBar()`

Comment: I have shared a link in my post. please have a look

Comment: okay let look at it for a moment...

Comment: is this how i should use it? ScrollUtil.scroll(chatScroll, 4);

Comment: Oh wait.. now it works ^_^ thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Use jTextArea.setEnabled(false);